# Offset a part of a dataframe by hours

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm have a portion of measurements where the instrument time has been configured wrong, and this needs to be corrected.

So I'm trying to offset or shift a part of my dataframe by 2 hours, but I can't seem to get it to work with my following code:

```
dfs['2015-03-23 10:45:00':'2015-03-23 13:15:00'].shift(freq=datetime.timedelta(hours=2))
```

I don't know if it can be done this easily though.

Hope someone understands my issue :)

---

```
>>> dfs.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 11979 entries, 2015-03-23 10:45:05 to 2015-03-23 16:19:32
Data columns (total 11 columns):
CH-1[V]        11979 non-null float64
CH-2[V]        11979 non-null float64
CH-3[V]        11979 non-null float64
CH-4[V]        11979 non-null float64
CH-5[V]        11979 non-null float64
CH-6[V]        11979 non-null float64
CH-7[V]        11979 non-null float64
CH-9[C]        11979 non-null float64
CH-10[C]       11979 non-null float64
Event          11979 non-null int64
Unnamed: 11    0 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(10), int64(1)
memory usage: 1.1 MB
```

Comment: Are you trying to just add 2 hours?

Comment: yes but only to that portion of data, I tried with +timedelta something, but didn't work either

Comment: Can you post `df.info()`, basically you can add Timedelta to individual columns

Comment: dfs.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 11979 entries, 2015-03-23 10:45:05 to 2015-03-23 16:19:32
Data columns (total 11 columns):
CH-1[V]        11979 non-null float64
CH-2[V]        11979 non-null float64
CH-3[V]        11979 non-null float64
CH-4[V]        11979 non-null float64
CH-5[V]        11979 non-null float64
CH-6[V]        11979 non-null float64
CH-9[C]        11979 non-null float64
CH-10[C]       11979 non-null float64
Event          11979 non-null int64
Unnamed: 11    0 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(10), int64(1)
memory usage: 1.1 MB

Comment: Please edit that into the question not as a comment, thanks

Comment: I can't edit the question... But I added it as an answer

Comment: There should be a row of links at the bottom of the question under the `python-3.x` and `pandas` tags. Clicking the `edit` link should allow you to edit your own question.

Comment: yes, but apparently I have to make more changes to be allowed to edit it... :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas Indexes are not mutable, so we can't change the index in-place.
We could however make the index a DataFrame column, modify the column, and then reset the index:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Suppose this is your `dfs`:
index = pd.date_range('2015-03-23 10:45:05', '2015-03-23 16:19:32', freq='T')
N = len(index)
dfs = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(N), index=index)

# move the index into a column
dfs = dfs.reset_index()
mask = (index >= '2015-03-23 10:45:00') & (index <= '2015-03-23 13:15:00')

# shift the masked values in the column
dfs.loc[mask, 'index'] += pd.Timedelta(hours=2)

# use the index column as the index
dfs = dfs.set_index(['index'])
```

This shows the index has been shifted by 2 hours:

```
In [124]: dfs.iloc[np.where(mask)[0].max()-1:].head(5)
Out[124]: 
                       0
index                   
2015-03-23 15:13:05  148
2015-03-23 15:14:05  149    <-- shifted by 2 hours
2015-03-23 13:15:05  150    <-- unchanged
2015-03-23 13:16:05  151
2015-03-23 13:17:05  152
```